# reset_selective on specific variable reset entire notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm working on Jupiter Notebook and I'd like to reset some specific variables after running a specific cell.

I'm running this command at the end of a cell `%reset_selective -f [var_name]` but it resetting variables in the entire notebook. What I'm doing wrong?